# Ping cmd con un número de hops/traceroute

Tags: cmd

me gustaría correr algún tipo de comando en cmd, para que me metiese en un archivo log el ping que se haga a google durante un numero de hops y si se pierde la conexión que aparezca a la hora que ha sido.

Es esto posible? En ese caso, Cómo podría hacerlo?

He intentado esto :

```
@echo off
set Address=google.com
:Loop
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Pinging %Address%
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
goto Loop
```

Pero solo me pilla 10 hops, no sé como cambiar para que el número sea mayor.

Gracias

He probado a añadir algo de código, alguna idea?

```
@echo off
set Address=google.com
:Loop
**PING -n 30 -h 100 127.0.0.1>nul**
echo Pinging %Address%
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
goto Loop
```

similar a esto :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824477/script-to-start-traceroute-if-ping-fails-output-to-log-help-please

Comment: el numero de hops te refieres al traceroute imagino? o al número de pings? En cualquiera de los casos, usando `/?` despues del comando puedes ver los parámetros que admite: `tracert  /?` o `ping /?`

Comment: correcto, al traceroute.

Comment: Pues `tracert -h saltos_máximos`

Comment: Umm, 

tracert -h 100 -j 10.114.25.130 -w 5 10.114.25.120

1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: Lo de la hora no lo acabo de entender... ese script se lanza automáticamente cada cierto tiempo?

Comment: cada vez que pierde la conexción se activa me refiero a este post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824477/script-to-start-traceroute-if-ping-fails-output-to-log-help-please

Comment: De todas maneras para hacerlo más simple, imagina que tengo 3 máquinas, las 3 conectadas a la red local, como podría saber desde una de ellas si ha perdido la conexión? es decir, hay algún script que vaya haciendo ping y luego yo pueda mirar a que hora se perdio la conexión?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando `tracert` tiene un parámetro `-h` para definir el número máximo de saltos. Más detalles [aquí](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows)

> tracert -d -h maximum_hops -j host-list -w timeout target_host
>   Descripción de los parámetros:
>
> -d 
>         Especifica que no se resuelvan las direcciones en nombres de host
>
> -h n_max_saltos
>         Especifica el número máximo de saltos para alcanzar el destino
>
> -j lista-host
>         Especifica la ruta de origen a lo largo de la lista de hosts
>
> -w tiempo_espera
>         Espera el número de milisegundos especificados en tiempo_espera para cada
>         respuesta
>
> host_destino
>         Especifica el nombre de la dirección IP del host de destino

El problema de mostrar la hora es tan sencillo como añadir a tu script:

```
@echo %TIME%
```

No he encontrado información sobre que valor devuelve el comando `tracert`, así que no sé si se puede detectar cuando ha habido un "timeout" para sólo guardar la hora en ese caso, sería cuestión de probar. Si, como parece según tu script, `ping` sí devuelve algo distinto de 0 cuando falla, ahí tienes una forma de comprobar si hay conexión antes de hacer el `tracert`.

Comment: Básicamente, lo tengo casi, sería una cosa así:

@echo off
set Address=google.com
:Loop
PING -n 30 -h 100 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Pinging %Address%
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
goto Loop

Pero me falta edtar el número de saltos ya que solo me pilla 10.

Comment: Sería una cosa así?

@echo off
set Address=google.com
:Loop
PING -n 5 -h 100 127.0.0.1>nul echo Pinging %Address%
%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop
echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
goto Loop

Comment: Realmente eso no me dice a la hora que se ha perdido la conexión...

Comment: 1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Esto es lo que obtengo, con estos comandos
tracert -h 100 -j 10.114.25.130 -w 5 10.114.25.120